# Math and variables in methods

Tags: variables, methods

I am trying to learn the basics by making up random code by playing around with methods.
I am doing one equation at a time then separating them with methods. Here is what i am trying to do:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class math2 {

public static int equation2(int number3, int number2) {
    number3 = number2 - 6;
    System.out.print("Your second number is " + number3 + ".");
    return number3;
}

public static int equation3(int number3, int number4) {
    number4 = number3 * 2;
    return number4;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int number;
    int number2;
    int number3;
    int number4;
    String firstline = "your first number is";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("pick a number between 1 and 10 to start with. ");
    number = in.nextInt();

    number2 = number + 4;
    System.out.printf("%s %d. ",firstline, number2); 
    equation2(number, number2);
    equation3(number3, number2);
}
```

}

The problem is it keeps telling me that variable "number3" needs to be initialized at the very bottom of the script and I can't do that since I get the first number as input from the Scanner class.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: *"...needs to be initialized ... I can't do that"* why?, your reasoning doesn't make sense, just give them default values of 0.

Comment: i wanted the equation to build off of the variable "number" which is input by the user and can be between 1 and 10. So wouldn't setting all the variables to 0 make the whole thing pointless. Again this is  just a made up script to practice methods.

Comment: No, using `int number = 0;` for example will just set the *starting* value, a variables value can be changed, hence the name *variable*